# Nested Select Query missing pointer and className -- Parse.com

Tags: ios, parse-platform

When I do a query that requests just some selected fields of a pointer, the response that is received does not include the pointer type and class name.

Example :

```
PFQuery * query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"ClassA"];
[query includeKey:@"column1"]; // This is a pointer with classname : ClassB
[query selectKeys:@[@"column1.subColumn1",@"column1.subColumn2"]];
```

The result is

```
"column1": {
        "createdAt": "2015-10-29T19:46:17.167Z",
        "subColumn1": "Some Value1",
        "subColumn2": "Some Value2",
        "objectId": "iCK9CpgKAh",
        "updatedAt": "2015-11-16T14:30:11.312Z"
      },
```

But, if I don't just select some fields, and include all subcolumns fields, it will work :

```
PFQuery * query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"ClassA"];
[query includeKey:@"column1"]; // This will select all fields inside column1
```

Result :

```
"column1": {
        "__type": "Pointer",
        "className": "ClassB",
        "createdAt": "2015-10-29T19:46:17.167Z",
        "subColumn1": "Some Value1",
        "subColumn2": "Some Value2",
        "subColumn3": "Some Value3",
        "objectId": "iCK9CpgKAh",
        "updatedAt": "2015-11-16T14:30:11.312Z"
      },
```

This create a problem when we use a `PFSubclassing`, because the pointer column is not treated as a pointer, but as a `NSDictionary`.

For example :

`PFClassA` and `PFClassB` are parse subclassess.

```
@interface PFClassB : PFObject<PFSubclassing>
@property (copy) NSString * subColumn1;
@property (copy) NSString * subColumn2;
@property (copy) NSString * subColumn2;
@end

@interface PFClassA : PFObject<PFSubclassing>
@property (strong) PFClassB * column1;
@end
```

When we do a query that just select 2 fields of the PFClassB like the above query,
the result of column1 will be a dictionary, and not a PFClassB.

Is there a workaround?

Thanks.

Comment: Nelley, not to cut down your efforts, but using Parse doesn't have to be this intense, if you read the docs for subclassing PFObjects, it says "A default implementation is provided by <PFObject> which should always be sufficient." .. and they are right, you don't need to do any subclassing if you have your database setup correctly and you use dynamic injection with initializers and such. Just saying, I've used parse for a long time, and never once have I needed to subclass using PFSubClassing.h. The parse sdk is open source, take a look at it, it's amazing, and does sufficient for everyone.

Comment: Hmm.. What do you mean by dynamic injection with initializers? We use PFSubclassing because as there are more classes & columns, it would be easy to set the values by the setting the properties directly without using it like a dictionary.

Comment: I mean, you don't need to refresh views or pull additional data in from the additional pulls if you just make a large pull, and then whenever you want to use the data, just parse the one big pull into additional NSMutableArrays or NSMutableSets and then pass them around the app. This depends on how much info you have on the data side. But if I pull in large tables from Parse, and these tables have pointers, then this is what I do. I just pull once and distrubute data to the other viewcontrollers. with refreshes from notifications.